# How does the OpenVINO toolkit program the FPGA?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, fpga, hardware-acceleration, intel-fpga

So, I've been meaning to find an answer to this question for about 3 months now. I'm just a beginner to the world of FPGA and hardware programming in general. I've only built the NIOS and tried a few things using quartus and a DE10 standard FPGA (which I don't have access to anymore). So, all I know is that a bitstream or netlist is created to program an FPGA, which I can do from the programmer feature in quartus after the design is complete.
My problem here is, how does OpenVINO manage to program the FPGA while the code is written in python and may use several libraries. I've already ordered OpenVINO starter platform FPGA.. but I need to know how this works. I've only seen like 1 python to HDL synthesizer, which is MyHDL and it looked quite complicated.

Answer (score 1):

OpenVINO FPGA depends on dlaplugin, Intel DLA architecture follows set of configuration methods, can be configured with Deep Learning Suite which is not provided as open source.

Intel FPGA runtime stack need to be installed to program an Intel FPGA.

```
aocl program device bitstream.aocx
```

after, dlaplugin helps to run application on FPGA